# Should there be Use cases = Functional requirements?

Tags: uml

Given UML, i'm having some confusions whith knowing if there should be the same amount of use cases as there are functional requirements.  so lets say :

```
  ()_______________________________________Update Info.
  ||__________________ Create User
  /\
```

since there are 2 use cases, should i create 2 Funciontal Requirements ?

Comment: **No.** Related articles: http://www.jamasoftware.com/blog/when-use-cases-arent-enough-part-1/ and http://agilemodeling.com/essays/agileRequirements.htm and http://www.sparxsystems.com/downloads/whitepapers/Requirements_Management_in_Enterprise_Architect.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I would say not.  That would only hold if there were a one-to-one relationship between requirements and Use Case, and that is not the case.

A requirement might result in multiple Use Cases.  For example, a requirement to "have password protection" might result in one Use Case for what happens when a correct password is entered, and another Use Case for when the wrong password is entered.

On the other hand, a requirement might result in zero Use Cases. For example, a requirement to do a calculation within 1 second would not need a Use Case.

Comment: Responsiveness or timeliness (e.g., doing a calculation within a set time) are typically non-functional requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use cases are functional requirements that have a direct benefit to an actor (which can be a real person or even an external system), typically as a result of some action from the actor's part. As there may be functional requirements within the system you are building (e.g., internal maintenance tasks), you would not need to have a use case for each functional requirement.

Comment: Should not be Use Cases linked rather to processes in BPM? What is the benefit of having Actors like `secretary`, `salesman` in your model? I would understand an Actor `System` that runs a use case `Maintenance task`. Is not Use case just a tool to model  functional requirements?

Comment: @VDohnal Use cases can be linked to implementations as BPMN processes. They could also become many other software entities (e.g., stored procedures, beans, scripts, embedded software). As you state, it is a tool to model functional requirements and, therefore, can drive many implementations.